# Does anyone know how can i get that searched user data from mongodb in the search bar called react-native-dynamic-search-bar

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

Does anyone know How can I do this in my social media app?

1: My project is a social media app in which I have search bar I am using react-native-dynamic-search-bar

2: So now I want that if a user search any user name in that searchbar than that user can see profile of that user for example "you ask your friend his Instagram and he give his insta id and than you go to insta and than search his id and now you can see his profile" I want same that if a user search any user name than he can see his profile you can see my Schema

3: I am using react native nodejs and mongodb and for search bar I am using react-native-dynamic-search-bar.

My Schema (nodejs):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Users = new Schema({
    name: String, 
    phoneNumber: String,
    profileImage: {
        type: String,
        default: 'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/146-1468479_my-profile-icon-blank-profile-picture-circle-hd.png'
    },
    about: String,
    selectedCountry: {
        type: Object
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("users", Users)
```

My utils file in which axios is there

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export async function apiReq(
    endPoint,
    data,
    method,
    headers,
    requestOptions = {}
) {

    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
        headers = {
            ...headers
        };

        if (method === 'get' || method === 'delete') {
            data = {
                ...requestOptions,
                ...data,
                headers
            };
        }

        axios[method](endPoint, data, { headers })
            .then(result => {
                const { data } = result;

                if (data.status === false) {
                    return rej(data);
                }

                return res(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                console.log(error && error.response, 'the error respne')
                if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
                    return rej({ ...error.response.data, msg: "Aunauthorized" })

                }
                if (error && error.response && error.response.data) {
                    if (!error.response.data.message) {
                        return rej({ ...error.response.data, msg: error.response.data.message || "Network Error" })
                    }
                    return rej(error.response.data)
                } else {
                    return rej({ message: "Network Error", msg: "Network Error" });
                }
            });
    });
}


export function apiPost(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
    return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'post', headers);
}

export function apiDelete(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
    return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'delete', headers);
}

export function apiGet(endPoint, data, headers = {}, requestOptions) {
    return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'get', headers, requestOptions);
}

export function apiPut(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
    return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'put', headers);
}


export const setItem = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, jsonValue)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error raised during setItem",e)
    }
  }

export const getItem = async (key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(data=>{
            resolve(JSON.parse(data))
        }).catch((error)=>{
            reject(error)
        })
    })
  }

  export const clearAllItem = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.clear()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error raised during setItem",e)
    }
  }
```

## file in which search bar is there

```
//import liraries
import React, { Component, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import HeaderComponent from '../../Components/HeaderComponent';
import HorizontalLine from '../../Components/HorizontalLine';
import WrapperContainer from '../../Components/WrapperContainer';
import imagePath from '../../constatns/imagePath';
import strings from '../../constatns/lang';
import navigationStrings from '../../constatns/navigationStrings';
import colors from '../../styles/colors';
import fontFamily from '../../styles/fontFamily';
import { moderateScale, moderateScaleVertical, textScale } from '../../styles/responsiveSize';
import styles from './styles';
import SearchBar from "react-native-dynamic-search-bar";


const Chats = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const leftCustomView = () => {
        return <TouchableOpacity>
            {data.length > 0 ? <Text>Edit</Text> : <View style={{ height: 20 }} />}
            <SearchBar                        // Search bar is here 
                fontColor="#c6c6c6"
                iconColor="#c6c6c6"
                shadowColor="#282828"
                cancelIconColor="#c6c6c6"
                backgroundColor="#ffff"
                placeholder="Search here"
                onChangeText={(text) => console.log(text)}
                onSearchPress={() => console.log("Search Icon is pressed")}
                onClearPress={() => this.filterList("")}
                onPress={() => alert("onPress")}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }

    const onPressRight = () => {
        navigation.navigate(navigationStrings.USERS)
    }

    const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Flat item</Text>

            </View>
        )
    }, [data])

    const listEmptyComponent = useCallback(() => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.listEmptyStyle}>
                <View style={{}}>
                    <Text style={styles.commStyle}>
                        {strings.TAP_ON} <Image source={imagePath.icEdit} /> <Text style={styles.commStyle}>{strings.IN_THE_TOP_RIGHT_}</Text>
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={{ ...styles.commStyle, color: colors.grey, marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(16) }}>{strings.YOU_CAN_CHAT_WITH_CONTACTS}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }, [data])

    return (
        <WrapperContainer
            containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 0, backgroundColor: '#000000' }}
        >
            <HeaderComponent
                rightPressActive={false}
                centerText={``}
                containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 8 }}
                leftCustomView={leftCustomView}
                isLeftView={true}
                rightImg={imagePath.icEdit}
                onPressRight={onPressRight}
            />

            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                ListEmptyComponent={listEmptyComponent}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}

            />


        </WrapperContainer>
    );
};

export default Chats;
```

Can anyone can tell how can i get user data in that search bar pls help me if you have done these type of proejects

Answer (score 0):

You should probably stock the result of your research in a reducer and bind your data variable to this reducer.
So after receiving the result of your mongoDB database you could dispatch it in your reducer. Like this your flatlist will be always updated with the last data you received from your api.